# Ubuntu 19.10, 2nd monitor via Thunderbolt dock sometimes limited to low resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, thunderbolt

I am running 19.10 on a Dell XPS15, with an external monitor connected via displayport to a Belkin Thunderbolt 3 Express Dock HD.

Most of the time, it works fine. But, a fair proportion of boots, the external screen is limited to 1024x768 instead of the usual 1920x1080. When this happens, its shown as 'Unknown..' in the 'Screen Display' panel of system settings.

When this happens, unplugging and replugging the Thunderbolt dock from USB-C usually get it detecting properly as 'LG Electronics 23"' with all expected resolutions available.

Does anyone have any suggestions I could try?

Update: in another variation of this issue, the resolution of the external monitor dropped from 1920x1080 to 1024x768 after the system has been running fine for a while. Unplugging and replugging the USB-C connection to the dock caused the monitor to be detected with all expected resolutions up to 1920x1080 again